# I can't -o "remount,rw" a usb drive

Tags: mount, usb-drive, readonly, read-write

I have a usb drive. It mounts as "ro." When I mount `-o "remount,rw"` I see this in dmesg.

hfsplus: filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  leaving read-only.

The verbose flag (`-v),`mount -v` doesn't tell me anything more. It actually says the mount worked,

```
mount: /dev/sdb1 mounted on /media/ecarroll/myDevice.
```

Running `fsck.hfsplus` on the block device, gets me

```
$ sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb1 
** /dev/sdb1
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume myDevice appears to be OK.
```

I wanted this to be clear in the above, but the `-o remount,force` also doesn't work.

```
sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdb1; sudo mount -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdb1 ; sudo dmesg -c
** /dev/sdb1
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume 2819010011 appears to be OK.
[97230.751669] hfsplus: filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  leaving read-only.
```

How do I mount this device read-write?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you get

```
** The volume myDevice appears to be OK.
```

You can unplug the device, and plug it back in and automount will take care of it with `-o rw`. I'm unaware of what it takes to get `-o rw` to work, after mount thinks the device is dirty, without pulling it and plugging it back in.

Comment: This does not explain or solve the issue at all.  I'm under the impression that you're facing a HFS bug with the clean bit but I've never investigated such issues before.

Comment: You would think so, but after putzing with this, and with -y, and with other options I'm inclined to think that mount just reread the dirty bit on `-o remount`.

Comment: I understand.  That's why I think it's a bug with the FS or partition driver since it doesn't happen on other partition types that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some one has already experience the issue take a look here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Here is an extract of the answer:

> First, make sure that you have hfsprogs installed. Example installation >command:
>
> sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
>
> Next, mount or remount the HFS+ drive; commands need to be as follows:
>
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint
>
> or
>
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /mount/point
>   ...
>
> Finally, if the drive was improperly unmounted or has otherwise become >partially corrupted run fsck.hfsplus ... as such:
>
> sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdXY

Also there is interesting information here for linux:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus

Comment: I did `fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdXY`, but mount `-o remount,rw` did not work.

Comment: ok but did you give a try adding the "force" parameter like this ?

Comment: sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint

Comment: Even if the force option overrode the issue, it wouldn't be a good solution to the problem.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm interested to understand why ?

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps:  Simply because forcing it overrides default FS protection.  Finding the root cause of the problem such as a driver or configuration issue would be **much** better.  I unfortunately don't have that answer though.

Comment: Forcing it doesn't work either. see question update.

Comment: Which distrib are you running here ?

Comment: Which distrib are you running here ?
It may be possible fsck doesn't work very well with hfs+ file system.

I have seen some people fixing the problem by using the geentoo package. 
You can compil it from here:
https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-fs/diskdev_cmds

If need you can do it like that i think:
tar zxf diskdev_cmds.tar.gz
cd diskdev_cmds
make -f Makefile.lnx
sudo cp fsck_hfs.tproj/fsck_hfs /usr/local/sbin/fsck.hfsplus

got those details from here:
https://debian-administration.org/users/lee/weblog/21

Hope that help.